# iPad, iphone linking and usage

Tags: ios-appstore, apple-id

If I had an iPhone only on my iTunes account, could I use someone else's iPad to download an app to my iphone? If I used the app on their iPad, would it show that my iPhone downloaded and used the app?

Comment: For purposes of your question, there are no devices on your iTunes/App Store account (iPhone, iPad, whatever) - only app purchases/downloads. Once an app is acquired, it can be downloaded to any device where you login with that same Apple ID. iTunes/App Store does not keep track of usage or what devices on your account have downloaded what apps, at least not to where a user can review that.

Answer (score 1):

Any app belongs to the Apple ID that purchased it.
You cannot transfer it to another account.

You could download it to another device only by logging in with the Apple ID that made the original purchase.

You do this by going to *Settings ➔ iTunes & App Store* then tap on *Apple ID*, then tap *Sign Out* (of whoever is signed in) Then sign in with your Apple ID.

Everything you've bought with that Apple ID (music, movies, apps) can be downloaded to that device.

If you used someone else's device to purchase an app using your own credentials, it would still be available for later download to your phone - though it would, of course, still be on the other person's device unless you deleted it afterwards. You can't remotely delete content from a device.

You can install apps on up to five iOS devices concurrently.

It goes without saying that letting someone else know your Apple ID login details could be potentially very unsafe.

Comment: Also keep in mind - if you login to another device with your Apple ID and purchase/download an app, your Apple ID will be required to download any updates for that app, and it will prompt the other person to enter your ID every time there is an update for that app. Basically, it would be a pain in the butt unless they have your password (even then it's not fun to juggle multiple accounts) - and unless you trust that person with your entire digital life, giving out your password is a Bad Idea™.